# Not able to get classes in domain package when trying to generate filtered entities

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

In my domain package I am not getting Book_.java,Client_.java,Author_.java,BorrowedBok_.java and Publisher_ .java classes after trying  to generate filtered entities in my jhipster application. Classes like BookQueryService.java, AuthorQueryService.java, ClientQueryService.java are generating and the criteria package is also getting generated but the classes like Book_*.java , Author*_.java are not getting generated. I have used the below given jdl file.

````
```
application {
  config {
    baseName library,
    applicationType microservice,
    authenticationType jwt
    packageName co.seedwill.app,
    prodDatabaseType mysql,
    cacheProvider no,
    buildTool maven,
clientFramework no,
testFrameworks [],
nativeLanguage en,
languages [en, fr]

}

entities *
 
}

DEFAULT_MIN_LENGTH = 4

DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH = 50

entity Publisher {
  name String required unique maxlength(100)
}

entity Author {
  firstName String required maxlength(DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH)
  lastName String required maxlength(DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH)
}

entity Client {
  firstName String required maxlength(DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH)
  lastName String  required maxlength(DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH)
  email String unique maxlength(DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH)
  address String maxlength(DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH)
  phone String maxlength(20)
}

entity Book{
  isbn String required unique minlength(5) maxlength(13)
  name String required maxlength(100)
  publishYear String required minlength(DEFAULT_MIN_LENGTH) maxlength(DEFAULT_MAX_LENGTH)
  copies Integer required
  cover ImageBlob
}

entity BorrowedBook{
  borrowDate LocalDate
}

relationship OneToOne {
  Book{publisher(name)} to Publisher
  BorrowedBook{book(name)} to Book
  BorrowedBook{Client(email)} to Client
}

relationship ManyToMany {
  Book{author(firstName)} to Author{book}
}

filter Book, Client, Author, BorrowedBook, Publisher

paginate Book, Client, Author, BorrowedBook, Publisher with pagination

service all with serviceImpl
```


I tried using the above jdl file and imported it to generate the application.
I was expecting the classes in domain like Book_,Client_ but did not get them . In the image below I have shown the classes which my friend is getting when he is generating application for filtered entities. He is getting classes like Amenities_.java , Authorities_.java. Can anyone help me why I am not getting such result.

image showing filtered entities, Please open this link =>(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBpIb.png)
````

Answer (score 0):

These classes are generated by maven or gradle who runs the [JPA Static Metamodel Generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/topical/html_single/metamodelgen/MetamodelGenerator.html). So you must run a build.